# Is there an argument for the "top" command to get a permanent result?

Tags: linux, command, command-line-arguments

The `top` command is live and constantly updating, not generating a permanent result. Can we add an argument for a permanent result (if it exists), or use a different command resulting in a definite and final response?

Comment: You can use the manpages command to know more about top. OR you can join unix.stackexchange.com for quick answers.

Comment: Top show the current status at the time of the report. What do you mean by "permanent"? Updating through scrolling rather than updating the screen?

Comment: I mean top command refreshes every 3 sec and give a new CPU utilization value right. I need only one instance value to be displayed and don't want the value to be refreshed after 3 sec.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
top -n1
```

should do the job. If you want to store the output in a file, you should add the -b option for batch mode.

Note that this is just a sample of usage at one time, not anything like a final answers as all the numbers in top vary over time even on the stablest of systems.

Comment: Thank you ... This helped me. Appreciate your support.